# AttributeError: Module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'GRUCell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying out the Tensorflow Seq2Seq Translate example and getting this error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'GRUCell'
```

I running on a server which has Tensorflow 0.10.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow's contrib's API supports GRUCell only on later version, i.e. 1.0. For the possible RNN cells in earlier versions, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.rnn/).